# Add ActiveX component to Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, activex

I have a fresh new excel file.
I'd like to add a basic `ActiveX` component from the `Developer` tab (`List Box`), but I get the "cannot insert object" error message.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893446/cannot-insert-object-error-when-adding-activex-control-like-microsoft-datagrid), [this](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Add-or-register-an-ActiveX-control-8fc743a1-e72b-4b55-af3a-85d326e53918), removing all the *.exd files as in [this](http://techfarley.com/2014/12/12/excel-activex-controls-cannot-insert-object-error/) and a few other dozen tricks (playing with `Trust Center Setting`).

I am on MS Office Professional Plus 2010

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27411399/62576

Comment: I saw that one. It actually worked when I upgraded to MS Office Plus 2013. I just needed to get rid of the *.exd files.